# Java - Finding the element of an array given the value?

Tags: java, arrays, element

In my Java program, I am simulating a parking garage. Suppose there are a random number of cars, let's say 7. Car number 1 is referred to by the value 1, car 2 is referred to by the value 2, and so on. Each car value is randomly stored in an array that represents the parking garage. Each element of the array represents a parking spot. I am trying to write a method that does the following: Suppose you want to know what parking space car number 4 is in. The value "4" is passed to the method, and the method will search the array for that value. I want the method to tell me which element of the array the value "4" was found in. Here is what I have so far for the method:

```
public int findBayOfCar(int carNumber)
{
    int index = -1;
    boolean found = false;

    while (!found)
    {
        if (cars[index] == carNumber)
        {

        }
        index++;
    }

}
```

Obviously it will not work because Java cannot compare cars[index] (which is an array of the Car type) to carNumber, which is an int. What can I do to correct this?

Comment: `cars[index].getNumber()` if you have a getter method.

Comment: what is 'cars' type. Is it its own class? Then you either have a getter method mentioned previously or a public variable you can access. Please post the code for how you set the value of each carNumber and we can help probably.

Answer (score 3):

You had many errors in such a small code.

1. `while (!found)` this means that you will continue searching until you found something, but what happens if the element we're searching is not on the array ? We will get the infamous **ArrayOutOfBoundsException** due the fact we will try to access non-existing array cell. Solution: `for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)` in order to run from the start until the size of the array.
2. **Found, now what ?** you didn't stopped when finding the car you were looking for, now we're setting it as `found = true` and stopping the search.

**Code:**

```
public int findBayOfCar(int carNumber)
{
    int foundAtBay = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)
    {
        if (cars[i].number == carNumber) // or whatever .Number or .number which identify the car number.
        {
            foundAtBay = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundAtBay;
}
```

Comment: You don't want to return a boolean _found_, you want to return the bay number in which the car was found.

Answer (score 1):

You should of reference your `Car` object to obtain its number:

```
public static int findBayOfCar(int carNumber, Car[] cars)
{
  int index = -1;
  boolean found = false;

  while (!found && index < cars.length -1)
  {
    index++;
    if (cars[index].getNumber() == carNumber)
    {
       found = true;
    }  
  }
  return found ? index : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and a brute-force solution to it would be `LinearSearch`:

```
for(int i=0; i < your_array_length; i++){
    if(cars[i] == carNumber){
      return i;
    }
}
return -1; //-1 represents that the car was not parked in any of the slots
```

Comment: Omit the `break;` after the `return` as it's unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

If your cars are just numbers, then:

```
int[] cars = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } ;
public int indexOf(int carNumber) {
    return Arrays.binarySearch(cars, carNumber);
}
```

If your cars are strings, then

```
String[] cars = new String[] { "car1", "car2", "car2" };
public int indexOf(int carNumber) {
    return Arrays.asList(cars).indexOf("car" + carNumber);
}
```

If your cars are objects, then

```
Car[] cars = new Car[] { new Car(), new Car(), new Car()  };
public Car indexOf(int carNumber) {
     return IntStream.range(0, cars.length).filter(c -> carNumber == cars[c].number).mapToObj(i -> cars[i]).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Or, with an ordinary loop:

```
Car[] cars = new Car[] { new Car(), new Car(), new Car() };
public int indexOf(int carNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (cars[i].number == carNumber) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```